# RabbitMQ not closing old connections with Celery

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I use Celery with Django to consume/publish tasks to RabbitMQ from ~20 workers across a few datacenters. After about a month or so, I'm at 8000 open socket descriptors and the number keeps increasing until I restart RabbitMQ. Often I "kill -9" the Celery worker process instead of shutting them down since I do not want to wait for jobs to finish. On the workers I do not see the connections that RabbitMQ is showing. Is there a way to purge the old connections from RabbitMQ?

I'm using Celery 3.1.13 and RabbitMQ 3.2.4, all on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm not using librabbitmq, but pyamqp.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue with the following 3-machine setup:

Worker (Ubuntu 14.04)

```
amqp==1.4.6
celery==3.1.13
kombu==3.0.21
```

Django App Server (Ubuntu 14.04)

```
amqp==1.4.2
celery==3.1.8
kombu==3.0.10
```

Rabbit MQ Server (Ubuntu 14.04 | rabbitmq-server 3.2.4)

---

Each task the worker received opened one connection that never closed (according to the RabbitMQ log) and consumed ~2-3 MB of memory.

I have since upgraded Celery to the latest version on my Django server and the socket descriptors and memory usage are holding steady.

I also see the connections close in the RabbitMQ log after the task completes, like so:

```
closing AMQP connection <0.12345.0> (192.168.1.100:54321 -> 192.168.1.100:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BROKER_HEARTBEAT` in Django's `settings.py` file.

RabbitMQ expects this value from the client(Celery in this case).

Refer to 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-broker_heartbeat for more details.